# How to show value of label control before the page is loaded completely?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a label control in a page with default value in an ASP.NET application. That value will be shown when the page is loaded. This is default scenario.

Now my need is, I change the value in run-time and immediately I need to show the value in the page before the page is loaded completely.

For e.g.,

```
<div>
    <asp:Label id="hdrStatus" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="text1" />
</div>
```

In page load, I change the value as follows

```
hdrStatus.Text = "text2";
```

Here, assume page is not loaded completely. Now I need to show the changed value 'text2' immediately.

Comment: Label value will be shown once page is loaded completely. Its ASP.NET page lifecycle. It will be rendered on page load only.

Comment: How can you show something if it is not loaded?

Comment: Actually in my web application, I included shopping API. When I click 'Refresh' button, first I call a client-side function to show value as "Fetching data. Please wait..." and then in server-side I call function which is for getting data from Google merchant account. Whenever I call API request, I check access token is expired or not. If expired, I need to show the value as 'Token Expired.. Getting new token..Please wait'. Meanwhile I call a method for getting new token.  How can I achieve this ?